# Transform list into dataframe selecting some particular elements as column names

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list:

```
['A1','some text','some text2','B1','some text','some text2,'some text3','A2',
'some text', 'some text2','B2','some text']
```

I'm looking to transform it into a dataframe or a dictionarty:

```
col1(or key)   col2(or value)
A1            'some text','some text2'
B1            'some text','some text2,'some text3'
A2            'some text', 'some text2'
B2            'some text'
```

i.e:

Elements between A1,B1,A2,B2 should be put into a different columns.

I tried to use a loop,and iterate:

```
for i in range(0,len(list):
    if list[i].startswith('A') or list[i].startswith('B'):
        ### Do something####
```

This was the logic that i was thinking.

Is there a better way or logic of doing this?

Comment: There is correction in your mentioned list. It should be : 
['A1','some text','some text2','B1','some text','some text2', 'some text3','A2', 'some text', 'some text2','B2','some text']. 

Also the for loop is incorrectly formed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us do it step by step

```
l=['A1','some text','some text2','B1','some text','some text2','some text3','A2','some text', 'some text2','B2','some text']
df=pd.DataFrame({'col2':l})
df['col1']=df.loc[df.col2.str.startswith(('A','B')), 'col2'] 
# select the column with condition put into another columns
df.col1.ffill(inplace=True)

newdf=df.query('col1!=col2').groupby('col1').col2.agg(','.join)
newdf#you can add reset_index(inplace=True) at the end 
Out[321]: 
col1
A1               some text,some text2
A2               some text,some text2
B1    some text,some text2,some text3
B2                          some text
Name: col2, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

We can be creative here with string matching `Series.str.match` then using `cumsum` to create our group indicator and finally use `GroupBy.agg` with `Series.str.split` to get our two columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col':lst})
mask = df['Col'].str.match('[AB]\d')
grps = mask.cumsum().rename(None)
df = df.groupby(grps).agg(', '.join)['Col'].str.split(', ', n=1, expand=True)
df.columns = ['Key', 'Value']

  Key                              Value
1  A1              some text, some text2
2  B1  some text, some text2, some text3
3  A2              some text, some text2
4  B2                          some text
```